# what is the difference between wordpress category and taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, categories

i just want to know that what is the difference between WordPress category and taxonomy. if you see both works similar so what is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, a taxonomy is a "way" of categorizing / tagging posts.

Read the [WordPress Taxonomies Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

Categories are a taxonomy.  They are a built-in taxonomy that comes by default.

Tags are also a taxonomy.  They are built-in also.

You may also create your own custom taxonomies that follow either a "heirarchical" structure (such as categories) or not (such as tags): [Custom Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies)

Answer (score 0):

**What are the WordPress Taxonomies?**

Taxonomy is a *simple way of organizing data* *in the WordPress* (post, pages, custom post types) by classify and group things.

~ By default Taxonomies are Tags and Categories which are used for posts.

**What are the WordPress Catagories?**

You can use categories to sort and group your blog posts into different sections. For example, a news website might have categories for their articles filed under News, Opinion, Weather, and Sports.

**Note:** T*axonomy is the way of organizing data* and *catagories are the front face of the directory where a certian type of data/information is stored.*

Hope this may helps.

Comment: for full info visit these links.  1-What is catagory ?https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/category/  2- What is taxonomy ? https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/